# What's the meaning of "floor discussion"?

Tags: word-meaning

What's a **floor discussion** in the following sentence?

> Promptness is necessary so that, by the time the Conference opens,
>   your material will have been compiled for use in a report, a panel
>   discussion, a workshop, a **floor discussion**, or a committee agenda
>   item.

Comment: Never heard this. Sounds like jargon. Even as a native speaker, I'd have to guess the meaning. Perhaps it means an open discussion to all members of some organization, not just a private panel.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi You mean it may mean a kind of discussion which takes place at the floor of, say for example, a conference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of **floor** that you're looking for is

> 5 c : the members of an assembly 
>   (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/floor)

You will see this used a lot in phrases like "[the Senate floor](http://www.senate.gov/floor/)" or "[we would like to open the floor for questions](http://www.c2es.org/docUploads/QandAonScienceSecurityEconomics.pdf)".

So a **floor discussion** is one between all of the members of the conference.

Answer (score 1):

A panel discussion is a discussion where only panelists discuss issues in a conference.

I think "floor discussion" is used to to mean ***Question and Answer (Q&A)" sessions*** where panelists and participants can discuss issues openly. This [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ta4lbgwTDdwC&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq="floor+discussion"&source=bl&ots=k7UnRx79F1&sig=4soX8Gkr6IuB8IZ3GY80ouA90Mo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCsL2Yk6nJAhVGlKYKHaI2BTwQ6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22floor%20discussion%22&f=false) is about a book whose subtitle is *Floor Discussion of "Regulatory Priorities for... Reform*" and it lists "presenter", "participants", "discussant in another session", and "chair".